# Sprite Kit OSX not loading start up code for spaceship

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

10.8.5 OSX

I am trying to run the basic start up code when you open up a new template for Sprite Kit in Xcode 5.0.2 (5A3005) but it always fails.  I have done nothing to alter the code from the basic template and am just trying to get the spaceship to appear on the mouse click.  The error message is as follows:

```
dyld`dyld_fatal_error:
0x7fff5fc0109c:  int3   
0x7fff5fc0109d:  nop
```

With this at the bottom where my NSLog information would appear:

> dyld: Library not loaded:
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/SpriteKit.framework/Versions/A/SpriteKit
>   Referenced from:
>   /Users/Brian/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/whynowork-hkyspuztyxslqletymjtomumimaq/Build/Products/Debug/whynowork.app/Contents/MacOS/whynowork
>   Reason: image not found (lldb)

Running Xcode with it selected as a Sprite Kit template for iOS runs fine, so I am wondering what is the difference with it being selected as OSX.  Is it a possibility of not having the right developer's license?  I want to create a simple game that I can work with controller input on OSX, not a touch screen game for iOS.  I apologize in advance if this is not worded correctly or on the wrong site.  Thanks!

Comment: What version of OS X are you using?

Comment: OSX 10.8.5 - just updated the initial post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SpriteKit is only available starting from OS X 10.9. Since you are using 10.8, upon start, your application will try to find the SpriteKit framework but is unable to, hence why it crashes in dyld (the dynamic linker).

Comment: //EDIT - Checking App store now for updated Mavericks.  Strange it doesn't autoupdate with the rest of the apps or software update.

Strange that it would be included with the Maverick update I downloaded.  I see no where how to update to 10.9 as well.  Is this for developers only and not available for public release?  As stated earlier, everything works fine when I am writing for iOS, I find it very peculiar iOS runs but not OSX…but I guess the framework is different.

Comment: @stickynugz The SpriteKit library is new, and Apple only includes it with OS X 10.9 (Mavericks) and iOS 7. They didn't release a version for OS X 10.8 (Mountain Lion), so you will not be able to test native Mac apps that use Sprite Kit until you upgrade to Mavericks. You *can* test iOS 7 apps in the simulator, though, even on 10.8.

Comment: Thanks JustSid and Kitsune Gonna check out the new update and see if that is the resolution.

Comment: @stickynugz It is. If you check the documentation, you will see that it reads that it's available starting with OS X 10.9 and iOS 7.