# Is it possible to use SpriteKit in a ScreenSaverView

Tags: swift, macos, sprite-kit, osx-elcapitan, screensaver

I am trying to create a screensaver with a sprite kit scene in Swift. When I first made the project, and before I added any SpriteKit code, I ran into the issue where the Screensaver built but only displayed "You cannot use the screensaver X with this version of OS X".

This was solved, or so I thought, by adding, to the build settings:

```
EMBEDDED_CONTENT_CONTAINS_SWIFT = YES;
```

Which seemed to do the trick. I thought this problem was behind me, but now that I have added a very simple SpriteKit scene (just displaying a BG color) the message is back. Can anyone confirm that a Screensaver CAN use SpriteKit, and if so, any ideas on how to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

[Edit]

Turns out, with using `ScreenSaverView` in 100% swift code, it does not like any swift objects outside of the ScreenSaverView swift file.  If you keep your code inside of the file, then you will not get this error.

--Old Stuff--

You should be able to add the SKView as a child to the ScreenSaverView, then do your sprite kit work in this SKView, other than that,  everything should work as expected as long as you are on a version of OSX that supports Sprite Kit,  if you could tell me the version you are testing on, I will run it in on mine.

Perhaps this is your problem, you are running on something < 10.9.

Source:
[Sprite Kit OSX not loading start up code for spaceship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20668609/sprite-kit-osx-not-loading-start-up-code-for-spaceship)

```
Code that works:

#import "screenSaverTestView.h"
#import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>
#import "screenSaverTest-Swift.h"
@implementation screenSaverTestView

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame isPreview:(BOOL)isPreview
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame isPreview:isPreview];
    if (self) {
        [self setAnimationTimeInterval:1/30.0];
        MyView *view = [[MyView alloc] init];
        [self addSubview:view];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)startAnimation
{
    [super startAnimation];
}

- (void)stopAnimation
{
    [super stopAnimation];
}

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect
{
    [super drawRect:rect];
}

- (void)animateOneFrame
{
    return;
}

- (BOOL)hasConfigureSheet
{
    return NO;
}

- (NSWindow*)configureSheet
{
    return nil;
}

@end
```

====SWIFT=====

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit
class MyView : SKView
{
    override func viewWillMoveToSuperview(newSuperview: NSView?) {
        self.presentScene(SKScene(size: self.frame.size));
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm running 10.11.13 and Xcode 7.2.1

I can get the SS to work without Sprite Kit but as soon as I add the SKView I go back to the error Screen. Is there something in Build Settings that I need to do to tell it to include SK support?

Also worth noting that I have a Desktop App Target using the SK view for testing, too, and that works fine.

Comment: OK I am on 10.10.5,  when I get home I will try it on my Mac Mini,  that has El Capitan on it, but as of right now, I was able to get it to compile fine

Comment: I added my test code for you to see, maybe you are doing something different

Comment: No luck, unfortunately - I keep getting the black screen of sadness and cryptic error messages.

Comment: let me add some nodes,  I am just doing a black screen now

Comment: I am not familiar with the ScreenSaverView,  is it possible for me to run it from inside XCode?  I have been installing and running, but I can't debug this way

Comment: No, you have to build the .saver file and install it. It is a huge pain, because the OS will not update the installed version even if you remove it and install an updated version - i have delete preferences each time and restart.

Comment: That explains why i keep getting. Black

Comment: you need to remove anything that starts with com.apple.screensaver from ~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104485/discussion-between-mike-bedar-and-knight0fdragon).